# VLOOKUP for last day of month

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an Excel spreadsheet to track expenses using =VLOOKUP.

In column C, I have the day of the month running down (starting with January), `1,2,...,31,1,2...,28,1,2,...31....`.
In column G, an amount (expense) is displayed based on column C from a lookup table.  My lookup table has 2 columns, R for day, and T for expense.

**The Vlookup is:**

```
=VLOOKUP($C2,$R$3:$T$30,3,FALSE)
```

My issue is that one of the days I want to use is not a specific day, like `1,2 or 30` but the last day of the month.  I do have a separate column with the full month to reference if need be.  Is there any way to incorporate this?  I have seen =EOMONTH, but am not sure if this then needs to be separate from the VLOOKUP table?

*Edit not by OP*

[image: SO19697681 question example]

The image shows an example for November, which in itself is a bad example since I have the lookup table set for the date of 30, so it works as expected (a workaround at the time), but if the month has 28, 29, or 31 days, the "deposit" does not come on the correct day [sorry, in my original post I put "expense", which is incorrect; but all references are correct].

In reality, what I did was just use `EOM` as my lookup value, and `EOM` in the day field, so I didn't need to change any formulas.

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of your table and add it to your question. I'm not understanding how your day numbers are laid out. Currently if you wanted the expense for March 13th, how would you get it? And if I understand correctly you want to return "the last day" of <Month>. For example "last day of May".

Comment: The image attached shows an example for November, which in itself is a bad example since I have the lookup table set for the date of 30, so it works as expected ( a workaround at the time), but if the month has 28, 29, or 31 days, the "deposit" does not come on the correct day [sorry, in my original post I put "expense", which is incorrect; but all references are correct]
[link](http://lpbj.net/images/excel_vlookup.gif)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making a few assumptions about where your non-specific date is located, what it is called etc, the following might serve:

```
=IF(C2="EOMONTH",VLOOKUP("EOMONTH",$R:$T,3,FALSE),VLOOKUP(DAY(C2),$R:$T,3,FALSE))
```

in G2 and copied down to suit.

[image: SO19697681 example]

Comment: thanks pnuts, I guess I was over thinking it.  In reality, what I did was just use "EOM" as my lookup value, and "EOM" in the day field, so I didn't need to change any formulas...